# What is the string I need for DataGridViewCellStyle.Format for adding a symbol before or after a number?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, format

Given I have a WinForms `DataGridView` and I am adding a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to it, how do I tell it that I want to suffix all data in it with a `°` symbol without modifying the raw data itself?

I have looked at changing the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` but I can only seem to get a fixed number of numeric digits to be suffixed with the symbol like so:

```
new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
    {
        Format = "0.000°"
    }
}
```

The above would cause the raw value of `4` to appear as `4.000°` when I want it to appear as `4°` and `4.1234` as `4.123°` when I want it to appear as `4.1234°`.  I'm not too concerned about text values for the moment but am looking for a generic format specifier that basically says: "Give me the raw value back" and then I'll add the `°` symbol on the end of that format specifier.  Can this be done?

Comment: See [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) and experiment a little. Pay close attention to what `#` does.

Comment: That's good but still less-than-ideal - if I don't know how many decimal places my number will contain, how do I know how many `#`s to place in the format specifier?

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution to apply a custom format to column, like adding a suffix, you can use [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event. The event raises when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display and you have the opportunity to apply custom formatting on it.

**Example - Add a suffix to cell value in DataGridView**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] {
    new { City ="Tehran", Temperature= 4.12345},
    new { City ="Kuala Lumpur", Temperature= 31.12345},
};

dataGridView1.CellFormatting += (obj, args) =>
{
    if (args.RowIndex >= 0 &&     /*Not the row header*/
        args.ColumnIndex == 1 &&  /*Desired column Index*/
        args.Value != null && args.Value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        args.Value = $"{args.Value}°";
    }
};
```

[image]

**Note:** For number values, a format like `"#.#############°"` also should do the trick:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Temperature"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.#############°"
```

Comment: Did you forget to accept this answer? ;)